# The other perspective for the infinite sum of 1+1+1+1+1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

we use many times using trick for the proof of infinite sum of any sequence or series so, when I was thinking about that then I am confused. Probably it is not formal way to find but I will write in tho bottom

$(1+1+1+1+1+...+)$  so we have this sequence and have to find this sum in infinite

It's the important point or critical point for the finding, $(1+1+1+1+1+...+)$

Why we can't bracket it? Like this,

$1+\left( 1+1\right)+\left( 1+1+1\right)+\left( 1+1+1+1\right)+...+$ And finally we can see the answer easily, $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+...+$ As we know this soluiton $-\dfrac {1} {12}$ Is it true is really sum of $(1+1+1+1+1+...+)$ equal to $-\dfrac {1} {12}$

Comment: +1 why the downvotes? It seems like a honest effort. It's nonsense, but that's why this site is here!

Comment: `As we know` Maybe if you added your proof that the divergent series $1+2+\dots$ does somehow sum up to $-1/12$ then you *might* be taken half-seriously.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series ... see the section on zeta function regularisation. $1+1+ \cdots = \zeta(0)= \color{red}{\frac{-1}{2}}$.

Comment: Using your grouping argument, but instead grouping one, two, four, eight, etc. terms, gives $1+2+4+8+\cdots+2^n+\cdots$, which, by analytic continuation of $x\mapsto1/(1-x)$ (a more elementary form of mathematical hocus-pocus than zeta-function regularization, but equally legitimate), equals $-1$.

Comment: The part with $-\frac{1}{12}$ is a multiple-duplicate, but the question contains another suggestion for an infinite sum, so I do not know whether it is actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

First you have do decide what you mean by the "sum" of a divergent series. Only then can you work out what manipulations are consistent and what aren't. By that logic, you could equally bracket it as $(1+1)+(1+1+1)+\dotsb = -1 + [ 1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+\dotsb ]$, so it's equal to itself ${}+1$.

I make my usual recommendation: read the first chapter of Hardy's *Divergent Series* (available online for free [here](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries)), which is an excellent primer on the sorts of methods that have been used to treat divergent series in a coherent and consistent manner.